# Error in creating instance of deployed contract using truffle console

Tags: tokens, erc-20, crowdsale, truffle-deployment, openzeppelin-contracts

I deployed Token and Crowdsale contract in separate migration files. During Migration, there was no error. Migration logs are share:

> Running migration: 2_deploy_token.js Deploying DappToken... ...
>   0xc1ed596e0249507186d75f2d42ba1c34e5b72697774baf9a283e0fb422214b70
>   DappToken: 0x949e24c24a79f437bbf75d3da7b9ba50235c2a8a Saving
>   successful migration to network... ...
>   0x1c8bc4b87bfbfa40bb16aa3eb6cf0341efc79f444b1e293abd1f0db394881d55
>   Saving artifacts... Running migration: 3_deploy_crowdsale.js Saving
>   successful migration to network... Deploying DappTokenCrowdsale... ...
>   0xdae8535756b9b7100af8d1a3bdf9d20b622c25dcb03aa40435b7f7019bfcdf7a
>   Saving artifacts...

After this, when I tried to create an instance of Crowdsale using truffle console as

```
truffle(ganache)> DappTokenCrowdsale.deployed().then(ic => tokensale = ic)
```

I got the error:

> **Error: DappTokenCrowdsale has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)**

Although i have successfully created the instance of DappToken contract. Related files are shared below:

**DappTokenCrowdsale.sol**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";

contract DappTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale {

  constructor(
    uint256 _rate,
    address _wallet,
    ERC20 _token
  )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    public
  {
  }
}
```

**3_deploy_crowdsale.js**

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");
const DappTokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require('DappTokenCrowdsale');

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const deployedToken = await DappToken.deployed();
    const _rate = 1000;
    const _wallet = accounts[1];
    const _token = deployedToken.address;

    await deployer.deploy(DappTokenCrowdsale, _rate, _wallet, _token);
};
```

**2_deploy_token.js**

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  const _name = "Dapp Token";
  const _symbol = "DAPP";
  const _decimals = 18;

  await deployer.deploy(DappToken, _name, _symbol, _decimals);
};
```

Comment: The migration message was like:

Comment: Running migration: 2_deploy_token.js
  Deploying DappToken...
  ... 0xc1ed596e0249507186d75f2d42ba1c34e5b72697774baf9a283e0fb422214b70
  DappToken: 0x949e24c24a79f437bbf75d3da7b9ba50235c2a8a
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x1c8bc4b87bfbfa40bb16aa3eb6cf0341efc79f444b1e293abd1f0db394881d55
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 3_deploy_crowdsale.js
Saving successful migration to network...
  Deploying DappTokenCrowdsale...
  ... 0xdae8535756b9b7100af8d1a3bdf9d20b622c25dcb03aa40435b7f7019bfcdf7a
Saving artifacts...

Comment: Your question seems a bit confusing. So at which step and in which file you got the error?

Comment: Hi @A.K. um, when I run migration commend, it looks all contracts(DappToken, DappTokenCrowdsale) were deployed. However, when I accessed truffle console, and tried to create an instance of those contracts, I cannot create for crowdsale. the message said, DappTokenCrowdsale has not been deployed even though there were no errors on the migration processing.

Comment: If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can also ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/ 
*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

Answer (score 0):

In case of migration you can't know for sure that the contract deployed, it returns transaction hash. You need to remove `async/await`(it is the simplest way) in order to see deployment result.

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const _name = "Dapp Token";
    const _symbol = "DAPP";
    const _decimals = 18;

    deployer.deploy(DappToken, _name, _symbol, _decimals)
        .then(function () {
             return deployer.deploy(Crowdsale, DappToken.address);
        });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I want to migrate Token and Crowdsale separately, and in deploy_crowdsale.js, how can I get the token address has been already deployed? I tried const deployedToken = DappToken.deployed(), but it is undefined..

Comment: @UnhaBack take a look on code above

Comment: Thanks @Aquila. Just curious. If I want to separate the migration file for Token and Crowdsale individually, is there any way to get the token address in Crowdsale migration file?

Comment: @UnhaBack yes, it is possible, there multiple ways to do this. for instance you can take a look https://github.com/oceanprotocol/keeper-contracts migration script for `OceanToken`

Comment: Thanks @Aqualia. I found the problem. Actually, I got the instance from the definition of DappToken on the top, but I defined again as "const deployedToken = DappToken.deployed()" it made error. Now, it is working well.